# HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway JSON array payload

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, spring-integration

I can't get an HTTP inbound adapter to convert a JSON array to a list of objects of type `SendgridTxEvent`, it always ends up with `ArrayList<LinkedHashMap>` instead of `List<SendgridTxEvent>`. The config:

```
public HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway sendgridMessageAdapter(@Qualifier("sendgridWebhookEvents") MessageChannel channel) {
        HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway httpInboundChannelAdapter = new HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway(false);

        RequestMapping mapping = new RequestMapping();
        mapping.setMethods(HttpMethod.POST);
        mapping.setPathPatterns("/webhook/sendgrid");

        ParameterizedTypeReference<List<SendgridTxEvent>> ptr = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<SendgridTxEvent>>() {
        };

        httpInboundChannelAdapter.setRequestMapping(mapping);
        httpInboundChannelAdapter.setRequestChannel(channel);
        httpInboundChannelAdapter.setRequestPayloadType(ResolvableType.forType(ptr));

        return httpInboundChannelAdapter;
    }
```

If I set the request payload type to `httpInboundChannelAdapter.setRequestPayloadType(ResolvableType.forType(SendgridTxEvent.class))` and feed a JSON object to it (instead of an array), jackson deserializes `SendgridTxEvent` correctly, so the problem only occurs with an array input. Input examples can be found [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Event_Webhook/event.html#sgeventid).

How do I go about consuming JSON arrays in an HTTP inbound adapter?

`SendgridTxEvent` class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SendgridTxEvent {
    public enum Event {
        PROCESSED,
        DROPPED,
        DELIVERED,
        BOUNCE,
        DEFERRED,
        OPEN,
        CLICK,
        UNSUBSCRIBE,
        SPAMREPORT;

        @JsonCreator
        public static Event forValue(String value) {
            return Event.valueOf(value.toUpperCase());
        }
    }

    private String email;
    private Long timestamp;
    private Event event;

    @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
    private List<String> category;
    private String sgEventId;
    private String sgMessageId;

//getters, setters

}
```

Comment: Please post other files as well . Mapping from json to object file ?

Comment: @AlexLemesios added `SendgridTxEvent`. Yes from JSON to a collection of objects

Comment: Do you have a wrapper for SendgridTxEvent ? Like a class that is a collection ?

Comment: @AlexLemesios no. I would think that I explicitly specified the target type as `ParameterizedTypeReference<List<SendgridTxEvent>>(){}`. I wonder why the adapter ignores it.

Comment: Seems like `org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport#extractRequestBody` doesn't preserve the actual type parameters calling `ResolvableType#resolve` and therefore it's impossible for HTTP inbound adapter to convert JSON arrays to collections of a desired type.

Comment: Looks like a bug or omission in the `HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport`. We need to consider support a `GenericHttpMessageConverter` there. Please, raise an issue for Spring Integration and we will fix it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've raised an issue to fix this in the Framework: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/2806

Meanwhile as a workaround I would suggest to expect a payload in the `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway` as `String` or `byte[]`, then use a POJO `@Transformer` downstream with direct conversion via `ObjectMapper` and already your expected `<List<SendgridTxEvent>` type.

Another simple option that you can expect just `SendgridTxEvent[].class` and than convert it into the list downstream.